# Trying to open window with switch in JS

Tags: javascript

I have used window.open in another .js file and it worked fine.
For some reason it will not work in this code. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

I thought it might be to do with my switch statement, but I do not know why.

I have tried making sure the syntax is correct and tried js lint and js hint.

```
function validateRedirect() {
   var choice;
   choice = prompt("Please enter a choice:\n 1: Google.com\n 2: TafeSA.edu.au \n 3: w3schools.com", "0");
   switch (choice) {
      case 1:
         window.open("http://www.google.com/", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 800, width = 800, resizable = 0");
         break;
      case 2:
         window.open("http://www.jslint.com", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 800, width = 800, resizable = 0");
         break;
      case 3:
         window.open("http://www.w3schools.org", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 800, width = 800, resizable = 0");
         break;
      default:
         if (!(choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice === null)) {
            alert("Please enter either 1, 2 or 3, or press cancel");
            validateRedirect();
         }
   }
   return;
}
```

I am a real beginner at this, so it may be obvious.

Comment: where are you calling your function from ?

Comment: I am calling it from a html onclick, and the everything including the validation and prompt works. When I added in the window.open method it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your `choice` variable to integer before you validate it in switch statement.

Do this just before your switch statement:

```
 choice = prompt("Please enter a choice:\n 1: Google.com\n 2: TafeSA.edu.au \n 3: w3schools.com","0");
 choice = parseInt(choice);
```

Here is the working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etpj86Lx/). Note that example will not open the new window but it shows how switch is working fine. On your page it should open new window.

Comment: The problem now is - If the choice variable is int, it doesn't recognize the value of null when you hit the cancel button (in the if statement) and it calls the function again. Then there is no way to get out of the prompt without choosing an option. Is a switch statement just the wrong way to do this, or is there a way around it?

Comment: The main point is switch statement needs a validated input, so you need to make sure you parseInt and also check for null before you go to the point where switch is being called.

Comment: I checked for null before I parse to Int, and it all works. Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

`prompt` returns a string. Thus, `choice` will be a string. A switch statement uses strict comparison ("==="), which means that the result from `prompt` will never equal any of the integers in the cases of the switch statement (since a string is never strictly equal to an integer)

Therefore, you must convert the `choice` to an integer, or compare it to the string representations of the appropriate numbers instead.